# Access properties of objects in an object

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I have 3 classes MetaA, MetaB and MetaC. Each have a number of properties.

There are certain situations where it would be nice to just have one class that contains the properties of all three Meta classes, called for example, MetaComposite. In the composite class, I have tried creating and instance of each MetaA, B and C in the hope that I could access the properties like so:

```
Meta Composite mc = new MetaComposite();
mc.MetaA.Property1 = "Hello";
```

Since C# does not allow multiple inheritance, what is the best way of making a class that is a composite of other classes? I could put fields and write getters and setters in the composite class to pass on the property values, but this would be a lot of duplicated code.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: C# supports multiple inheritance through interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason to have all properties on class level?
Why not simply use exactly what you wrote?

```
class MetaComposite
{
    public MetaAClass MetaA { get; private set; }
    public MetaBClass MetaB { get; private set; }
    public MetaCClass MetaC { get; private set; }

    public MetaComposite()
    {
         MetaA = new MetaAClass();
         MetaB = new MetaBClass();
         MetaC = new MetaCClass();
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var composite = new MetaComposite();
    composite.MetaA.Field1 = 1;
    composite.MetaB.Field2 = '2';
    composite.MetaC.Field3 = new MetaDClass();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about creating interfaces for all three Meta classes and have the MetaComposite class implement all three of these interfaces. The MetaComposite class can instantiated the correct Meta class and call it to execute the desired property.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IMeta1
{
   int Metaproperty1 {get; set;}
}

public interface IMeta2
{
   int Metaproperty2 {get; set;}
}

public interface IMeta3
{
   int Metaproperty3 {get; set;}
}

public class MetaComposite : IMeta1, IMeta2, IMeta3
{
    private readonly Meta1 _meta1;
    private readonly Meta2 _meta2;
    private readonly Meta3 _meta3;

    public MetaComposite()
    {
        _meta1 = new Meta1();
        _meta2 = new Meta2();
        _meta3 = new Meta3();
    }

    public int Property1 
    {
        get { return _meta1.Property1; }
        set { _meta1.Property1 = value; }
    }

    public int Property2 
    {
        get { return _meta2.Property2; }
        set { _meta2.Property2 = value; }
    }

    public int Property3
    {
        get { return _meta3.Property3; }
        set { _meta3.Property3 = value; }
    }
}
```